# Change width on mousedown and mousemove in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, dom-events, addeventlistener

I want to build a hook that changes the width of an element on `mousemove` and `mousedown` events.

I'm using the following code (that is actually working):

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect, useRef } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/react";
import ReactDOM from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/react-dom";

const useMouseDelta = (initialWidth) => {
  const [dragging, setDragging] = useState(false);
  const [result, setResult] = useState(initialWidth);
  const origin = useRef(initialWidth);

  const handleMouseDown = useCallback((e) => {
    origin.current = e.clientX;
    setDragging(true);
  }, []);

  const handleMouseUp = useCallback((e) => {
    setDragging(false);
  }, []);

  const handleMouseMove = useCallback((e) => {
      if (!dragging) {
        return;
      }
      setResult(result + (e.clientX - origin.current));
    },
    [dragging]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseDown);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseDown);
      window.removeEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);
      window.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
    };
  }, [dragging]);

  return result;
};


const Test = () => {
  const width = useMouseDelta(400);
  return (
    <div className="container" style={{width: width}}>
      <div className="resize"></div>
    </div> 
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

However, I'm seeing this warning in ESLint:

`React Hook useCallback has a missing dependency: 'result'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. You can also do a functional update 'setResult(r => ...)' if you only need 'result' in the 'setResult' call`

So I change it to:

`setResult(r => r + (e.clientX - origin.current));`

Now the drag is not working as desired anymore.

An example can be found here:
[CodePen example](https://codepen.io/peterbartels/pen/MWmpOLN)

Comment: When I include it to dependency array it seems to working fine. Isn't it?

Comment: @KonstantinModin Yes that does work. But I still don't know why the setResult with a function inside isn't working, though.

Comment: When adding result it to the dependency array, it doesn't work properly anymore

Comment: Is it possible to see the eslint warnings inside codepen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You don't need to store `origin`, but you need to store `previousClientX` with [`useRef()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) and add just a change of [`clientX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/clientX) between two events.
2. You don't need to store `dragging` with [`useState()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate), [`useRef()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) is enough.
3. You need to add all handlers to the dependencies list in your [`useEffect()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect).

**The improved code**:

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/sergdenisov/pen/WNjZyVb?editors=0010)

```
import React, {
  useState,
  useCallback,
  useEffect,
  useRef
} from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/react";
import ReactDOM from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/react-dom";

const useMouseDelta = (initialWidth) => {
  const [result, setResult] = useState(initialWidth);
  const dragging = useRef(false);
  const previousClientX = useRef(0);

  const handleMouseMove = useCallback((e) => {
    if (!dragging.current) {
      return;
    }

    setResult((result) => {
      const change = e.clientX - previousClientX.current;
      previousClientX.current = e.clientX;
      return result + change;
    });
  }, []);

  const handleMouseDown = useCallback((e) => {
    previousClientX.current = e.clientX;
    dragging.current = true;
  }, []);

  const handleMouseUp = useCallback((e) => {
    dragging.current = false;
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("mousedown", handleMouseDown);
    window.addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleMouseDown);
      window.removeEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
      window.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
    };
  }, [handleMouseDown, handleMouseUp, handleMouseMove]);

  return result;
};

const Test = () => {
  const width = useMouseDelta(400);

  return (
    <div className="container" style={{ width }}>
      <div className="resize" />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 2):

In this Effect you can add all the dependencies like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseDown);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseDown);
      window.removeEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);
      window.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
    };
  }, [dragging, handleMouseDown, handleMouseUp, handleMouseMove]);
```

In the handleMouseMove it's a bit more tricky. It's ommited on purpose, so that it will only see the 'currentWidth' of the component and not the updates versions. The setResult can be used like this:

```
  const handleMouseMove = useCallback((e) => {
      if (!dragging) {
        return;
      }
      setResult((result) => result + (e.clientX - origin.current));
    },
    [dragging]
  );
```

Then the warning will not come up, but you will see that it will always see the updated value and it will cause extra additions.

A solution would be to store the current witdth in a different state like this in useMouseDelta and then it can be added as a dependency:

```
const useMouseDelta = (initialWidth: number) => {
  // The distance the mouse has moved since `mousedown`.
  const [dragging, setDragging] = useState(false);
  const [result, setResult] = useState(initialWidth);
  const [currentWidth, setCurrentWidth] = useState(initialWidth);

  // Original position independent of any dragging.  Updated when done dragging.
  const origin = useRef(initialWidth);

  const handleMouseDown = useCallback((e) => {
    origin.current = e.clientX;
    setDragging(true);
  }, []);

  const handleMouseUp = useCallback(
    (e) => {
      setDragging(false);
      setCurrentWidth(result);
    },
    [result]
  );

  const handleMouseMove = useCallback(
    (e) => {
      if (!dragging) {
        return;
      }
      setResult(() => currentWidth + e.clientX - origin.current);
    },
    [currentWidth, dragging]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("mousedown", handleMouseDown);
    window.addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleMouseDown);
      window.removeEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
      window.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
    };
  }, [dragging, handleMouseDown, handleMouseUp, handleMouseMove]);

  return result;
};
```